# plotting more than one data set in R using xyplot

Tags: r, lattice

I'd like to plot multiple data sets on this graph but I can't figure out how.
I need to put `t`, `u`, `v`, `w` on the already functioning `xyplot`.

```
library(lattice)
x <- rnorm(250, 5, .5)
y <- rnorm(250, 5, .4)

t <- rnorm(200, 6, .7)
u <- rnorm(200, 6, .6)

v <- rnorm(150, 7, .9)
w <- rnorm(150, 7, .8)

xyplot(y ~ x, xlab="", ylab="",
   par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col="transparent")),
   panel = function(x, y,t,u,...) { 
     panel.xyplot(x, y, col=3, pch=16)
     panel.rug(x, y, col=8, x.units = rep("snpc", 2), y.units = rep("snpc", 
2), ...)})
```

Comment: [ggplot2](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_group_order.html) is a easy way.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to make a scatter plot of points whose coordinates are defined by (x, y), (t, u), & (v, w), the following should work for you:

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = c(x, t, v), 
                 V2 = c(y, u, w), 
                 V3 = c(rep("xy", length(x)), rep("tu", length(t)), rep("vw", length(v))))

xyplot(V1 ~ V2, group = V3, data = df, 
       xlab="", ylab="",
       par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col="transparent")),
       panel = function(x, y, groups...) {
         panel.xyplot(x, y, 
                      col = c("red", "blue", "green"), # change this if you want other colours
                      pch=16)
         panel.rug(x, y, col = 8, x.units = rep("snpc", 2), y.units = rep("snpc", 2))
       })
```

[image: lattice xyplot]

If you're looking to plot them into the chart in some other way, please clarify in your question.